# Why is there a fee to import old transactions when using mymonero web wallet?

Tags: mymonero

When opening and old wallet created by simplewallet, I'm asked for a fee to import old transactions, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to what Jolly Mort correctly said (rescanning the blockchain is a heavy process on the server, which the Mymonero operators want to discouraged), it is possible to have a wallet created in Mymonero, then import it in simplewallet. This will not incur a fee in Mymonero, and you will have a wallet which you can use in both.

See for instance 
[If I saved my view key and spend key can I recover my wallet if my mnemonic seed is lost?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/55/if-i-saved-my-view-key-and-spend-key-can-i-recover-my-wallet-if-my-mnemonic-seed/59#59) for instructions on how to import a wallet from keys with simplewallet (Mymonero will show you the keys to your address).

Answer (score 9):

Re-scanning the blockchain from 0 consumes server resources and takes time. The fee is there to discourage this use case, but providing the utility if it's really required for some users.

If a new wallet is generated, the server doesn't need to re-scan the blockchain as it knows that the wallet has not been used before.

Comment: That is almost $20. Seems high.

Comment: Yeah, it's ridicoulous, and I believe it's intentionally like that. There is really no reason to use the import function,  unless you created your wallet elsewhere AND didn't use it on mymonero before receiving a payment. If you're not willing to pay, you can always use simplewallet and transfer to a fresh mymonero wallet.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/483/72) from user36303 was correct at the time but is no longer up to date. Following the large rise in XMR prices a few months back fluffypony lowered the import fee from 10XMR to 1XMR. The following message is now displayed on [MyMonero.com](https://mymonero.com/) when attempting to import old transactions:

> **Import transactions**
>
> Import your transactions from the entire blockchain
>
> To import all your previous transactions and account balance you have to pay a once-off import fee of **1 XMR** to the account listed below. The command to make the payment has already been prepared to make it easy for you to copy and paste it into simplewallet.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the Import Instructions modal.

IF you didn't create a fresh wallet with MyMonero but you imported an already-created one (like from the GUI) by using your:

(a) mnemonic seed, or (b) address and keys,

then you can send MyMonero a small fee in order to subsidize the MyMonero back-end (server / hosting) doing the very computationally expensive job of scanning the entire blockchain for your account transaction background and balance.