# How do you import a wallet from the private keys into simplewallet?

Tags: viewkey, monero-wallet-cli, privatekey, spend-key, keys-file

Is there a way you can import a wallet into simplewallet from the private spend key and private view key? I know you can import the view key to create a view wallet, but I can't see how to import the private spend key.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://monero.stackexchange.com/q/55/121 but maybe this duplicate is okay since the title will be easier to find for those searching for "import from private keys"

Comment: @cooldude45 Sometimes the most searched question on Google is closed as a duplicate. That's not a bad thing, since it links back to the original question.