# converting view-only wallet to spend wallet

Tags: cold-storage, wallet-recovery

I created an offline paper wallet, then use the view key to create a view-only wallet with "monero-wallet-cli --generate-from-view-key" command.  My test send from an exchange to this wallet works, and show up the balance.  What do I need to do to be able to send from this wallet?

Comment: Probably just making a new wallet would work.

Answer (score 5):

You do the same, except using `monero-wallet-cli --generate-from-keys`, which will use the spend key in addition to the view key.

You will be prompted for the information when you run this.

See a guide for using `--generate-from-keys` here: [If I saved my view key and spend key can I recover my wallet if my mnemonic seed is lost?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/55/if-i-saved-my-view-key-and-spend-key-can-i-recover-my-wallet-if-my-mnemonic-seed?rq=1)

Comment: ahhh... I was using `./monero-wallet-cli --restore-deterministic-wallet`.  Your suggestion makes sense.  I'll give it a go and report back.

Comment: It's not really converting, though, since we're making a new wallet. We don't have a function to convert, yet. For wishlist: it would be nice to have a command inside simplewallet which would let the user convert it by typing in the spend key (or the entire mnemonic). The wallet would then have to check all the outputs if they've been spent or not and you'd see the correct balance shortly after