# Can I retroactively add the spendkey to a watch only wallet?

Tags: cold-storage, spend-key, watch-only-wallet

If yes, how can this be done?

The reason being that I want to spend the balance, but I don't want to set the wallet up again and sync it as this takes a while. It's just a time saver I'm hoping for.

Comment: Was pondering something similar as well. This would be a good feature request IMO. To be able to make a wallet full/view without re-sync.

Comment: Looks similar to this question: [converting view-only wallet to spend wallet](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1870/converting-view-only-wallet-to-spend-wallet?rq=1).

Comment: @dpzz see Jolly Mort's comment on that answer. It's not converting the view only wallet, it's creating a new wallet with the spend key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not possible.

There is no function to do so in the current software. I did a test where I replaced the .keys file of the view-wallet with the .keys file of its full-wallet counterpart but that resulted in an error, as expected.

Comment: Also, considering the watch-only wallet only has a record of inputs, the blockchain would have to be synced anyway to find the outputs, thereby negating any time-saving by having the inputs already synced.

Comment: That's one and the same thing. The full wallet would take the list of inputs already made by the watch wallet and check each for spent status. It wouldn't have to rescan as all have already been "found" with the viewkey. What's missing is to make a key image for each one and perform a simple look-up to check for spent status. So, you would actually save time if conversion was possible.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the correction and useful info. Well...seems like it could still be a handy feature.

Answer (score 2):

As per Jolly Mort's comment, this is currently not possible.