# Can I recover my wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I forgot my mnemonic seed. I only have the wallet address, monero payment id and monero transaction id (hash). Is there something I can do to recover my coins or are they lost forever?

Answer (score 2):

No. A wallet address, monero payment id, and monero transaction id are not enough to recover your wallet. You will need the **mnemonic seed** or **spend and view keys**

Comment: Only the mnemonic seed or private spend key are required.

Comment: @assylias The wallet will require both keys to recover but I think technically you could generate the view key from the spend key though I’ve never done that. See - https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/55/if-i-saved-my-view-key-and-spend-key-can-i-recover-my-wallet-if-my-mnemonic-seed. If this is incorrect please let us know what steps to take to recover the wallet from only the view key

Comment: If you have the private spend key, you can enter it on (a local, not connected to the internet version of) [this site](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html) in the hexa seed box and click on "Gen 1." to recreate the seed. More info: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6d0qb6/monero_only_private_spend_key_and_public_address/

Comment: Can anyone actually confirm that this works with the latest version?